# Why is there Inequality in Fatou's Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm studying measure theory for the first time, and I just came across Fatou's Lemma.

Why isn't it true that for any sequence of functions $\left\{ f_n \right\}$ in $L^+$ we always have that $$\int \displaystyle \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu =\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n d\mu\ ?$$

Comment: Since you have figured this out, it is also useful to know the form of Fatou's Lemma $$\int_E f \leq \text{liminf} \int_E f_n $$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

consider the sequence of functions$$f_n = n 1_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}  $$

Notice

$$ \int f_n = 1 \implies \lim \int f_n = 1 \implies \liminf \int f_n = 1$$

But, $\lim f_n = 0 \implies \liminf f_n = 0 \implies \int (\liminf f_n ) = 0 $

Comment: Sorry for the decade-later reply, but I was curious as to why the limit of fn itself was 0. Are we working in the extended real line with the measure theoretic convention that infinity times 0 equals 0?

Answer (score 15):

There could be several reasons for which the equality does not hold:

- if the measure space has infinite measure, mass can "escape", for example with $f_n:=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$ on the real line;
- in the case of a finite measure space, there could be a huge diminution of the measure of the support of $f_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity;
- oscillation of the function, for example $f_n(x):=\sin^2(n\pi x)$ on the unit interval.

Actually, taking $f_{2n}=g$ and $f_{2n+1}=h$ would give
$$
\int \min\{g,h\}=\min\left\{\int g,\int h \right\},
$$
which cannot hold, for example when $g$ and $h$ are indicator functions of disjoint sets of positive measure.